# Can I create a member variable that is a type parameter of a generic?

Tags: java, generics, singleton, type-parameter, member-variables

I have a lot of proxy classes around services, and all look (almost) the same. Can I reduce code duplication somehow by using a **generics singleton class**, that takes the `Service` and `Port` class as **type parameters**?

This is my completely wrong code with what I want to get started:

```
public class MyProxy<S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider>
{
  private static final MyProxy<S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider> instance
      = new Proxy<S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider>();
  private S service;

  public static MyProxy<S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider> getInstance() {
    return instance;
  }

}
```

- The **type parameters** for `MyProxy` I assume to be correct.
- Can I declare a static `instance` singleton **member variable**, and how?
- The member variable `service` should be more easy, can I have a *type parameter* as a member, anyway?
- How about the **return type** of `getInstance()`, how to I write it?

Comment: By declaring a singleton, you'll have to specify wildcard and make unchecked casts then. Don't think that's what you're expecting. This shows that you implicitly consider MyProxy<S, P> be a subclass of MyProxy<Service, BindingProvider> which is semantically wrong in Java (though it might work). Maybe a reply is coming if a find a suitable solution

Comment: As a comparative example, you might have a look at java.util.Collections that has a singleton for EMPTY_LIST for example and a generic method emptyList() whose javadoc states that a new instance shall be created on each call (though the singleton could just have been casted)

Comment: @Antoine Marques: empty list is stateless while the supposed wrapper here is not.

Comment: @towi I think you are on the wrong path thinking you can collapse multiple singleton proxy classes into one *singleton* class. If you still have multiple services you want to wrap you will need *multiple* instances of your single wrapper class.

Comment: @Holger Maybe you are right. Since I come from C++ I assumed that for each different type argument I get a specialized class version generated, no? In C++ when I define `stack<T>` the use of `stack<int>` and `stack<double>` creates two classes with its own static members.

Comment: Generics are not templates. A single generic class remains a single class.

Comment: @Holger I did not know that. That is the answer to my question -- in a way ;-) Wrong assumption... I guess now that the "generated code" is only cast-code then, not a whole class.

Comment: Inside the generic class there are not even casts. Only the code *using* a generic class might have synthetic casts where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code corresponding to my first comment. As i said this involves unchecked casts.

```
public static class MyProxy<S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider> {

    private static final MyProxy<? extends Service, ? extends BindingProvider> instance = new Proxy<Service, BindingProvider>();

    private S service;

    public static <S extends Service, P extends BindingProvider> MyProxy<S, P> getInstance() {
        return (MyProxy<S, P>) instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood though the use of the `service` field

Comment: The class is not complete yet. `service` is used by other methods. I needed a simple member variable declared from a type argument. What does the `?` mean in the `<...>´s exactly?

Comment: Hrmm `new Proxy<Service, BindingProvider>();` makes me skeptical if my approach works at all in Java, as @Holger pointed out. When I use this class twicem say `MyProxy<ServiceA,PortA> p = new MyProxy<ServiceA,PortB>()` and `MyProxy<ServiceB,PortB> q = new MyProxy<ServiceA,PortB>()` -- will I really have *two* distinguashable `instance`-members, as I intended?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for such a proxy skeleton with a single type parameter:

```
public class MyProxy<S extends Service> {

  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, MyProxy<?>> INSTANCES
      = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private S service;// could be final depending on your demands
  private final Class<S> type;

  MyProxy(Class<S> serviceType, S serviceInstance) {
    service=serviceInstance;
    type=serviceType;
  }

  /**
   * Helper method for a runtime cast.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <S extends Service> MyProxy<S> cast(Class<S> serviceType) {
    if(serviceType!=type) throw new ClassCastException(type+" != "+serviceType);
    return (MyProxy<S>)this;
  }

  /**
   * Get the proxy for type {@code sType}.
   */
  public static <S extends Service> MyProxy<S> getInstance(Class<S> sType) {

    MyProxy<?> old=INSTANCES.get(sType);
    if(old!=null) return old.cast(sType);

    MyProxy<S> proxy=allocateNewProxy(sType);

    old=INSTANCES.putIfAbsent(sType, proxy);
    return old==null? proxy: old.cast(sType);
  }
}
```

So you can use it the following way:

```
MyProxy<A> proxyA=MyProxy.getInstance(A.class);
```

Assuming that A is a subclass/implementation of `Service`

Comment: Can we not get rid of the `sType` parameter? `S s = new S()` followed by `INSTANCES.get(s.getClass());` -- or somethe other way to `S` to get to its class?

Comment: No. Generics are implemented via type erasure so the value of a type parameter exists on compile time only. Note that `Foo.class` is not an expensive operation.

Comment: No, but a bit of code duplication, which one may get rid of. Since Java generics work in the return type as well, don't they (unlike C++). Like my code `public static <T> T toType(String xmlString) {
    JAXBElement jbel = ...;
    return (T) jbel.getValue();
  }` -- which I use often and could devise after lots of try-and-arror with my limited generics understanding.

Comment: A method like `public static <T> T toType(String xmlString)` is broken by design. I could use it to assign the result to *any* variable type which surely breaks at runtime as the result of that method cannot be of any kind. How about `Integer i=toType(xmlString);` and `Button b=toType(xmlString);`? At least one of these calls *must* break at runtime.

Comment: By the way your implementation of that `toType` method must have produced a compiler warning, for a good reason. You should not ignore it.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I cant see a warning. Although, I use netbeans and assume I get a warning in the sidebar. The console maven messages run through too fast, anyway. But let's check... No, I touched the file, `mvn compile` does only emit `[INFO]`s, no warnings, but says "Compiling 1 source file", though. Here a long [excerpt](http://pastebin.com/ykXKAscp).

Comment: In case of Netbeans you might have received a message like `Note: ….java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`